# The data folder doesn't included when I upload my package to pypi?

Tags: python, package, pypi, twine, sdist

I created a package and I wanted to upload it to pypi. The structure of files is like this:

```
AAA
├── AAA
│   ├── AAA.py
│   ├── BBB.py
│   ├── CCC.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── DDD.py
│
├── data
│   ├── table2.json
│   └── table2.json
│
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

I used `python3 setup.py sdist` and `twine upload dist/*` to upload the package into pypi. But when I installed my own package there was not any `data` folder. I came back to `dist` folder but again there was not any data folder in the `AAA.tar.gz`.

I'm confused what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you configure package data? https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Thank you. I read the page than you sent and I added `package_dir={'AAA': 'AAA'}` to setup.py and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following page suggested by [@Gonzalo Odiard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3969110/gonzalo-odiard):

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

First, I moved `data` folder to `AAA` folder and then I added `package_dir={'AAA': 'AAA'}` to `setup.py` and the problem was solved.